# amCharts - adding padding for a smoothed line serial chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Can I have amCharts compute a maximum value for the Y axis such as the smoothed line isn't stretched outside the chart div area?

Or can I somehow specify a spacer value, instead of iterating all my values, seeing which is the highest and then setting it myself?

I tried using marginTop, but that simply squeezes the viewing area. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to add padding is to change your axis' `minimum`/`maximum`. There isn't a direct way to compute an optimal min/max value, but you can set the valueAxis' [`minMaxMultiplier`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minMaxMultiplier) to pad the automatically calculated min/max values by a small multiplier, i.e. 1.05:

```
valueAxes: [{
  // ...
  minMaxMultiplier: 1.05,
  // ...
}]
```

Note that the `minMaxMultiplier` does not affect manually set `minimum` and `maximum` values in your valueAxis, so you'll have to remove one or both, depending on how you want that property to affect your axis (you can force  your axis to start from 0 if you set the `minimum` if you don't want `minMaxMultiplier` creating an unwanted negative axis, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Use this two properties, it will auto calculate your value axis based on your data and guides.

`'valueAxes': {
                'includeAllValues': true,
                'includeGuidesInMinMax': true
             }`

> includeAllValues: If you set it to true, minimum and maximum of value axis will not change while zooming/scrolling.
>
> includeGuidesInMinMax: Specifies whether guide values should be included when calculating min and max of the axis.

[Doc](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#includeAllValues)

Also, don't forget to delete this settings to let amCharts recalculate max and minimum value:

> max, maximum, maximumDate, min, minimum, minimumDate

Answer (score 1):

For AmChart v4:

```
    valueAxis.extraMin = 0.1;
    valueAxis.extraMax = 0.1;
```

ref: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/value-axis/#Relatively_expanding_the_scale